# See the entire class structure of a solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am a trainee programmer and given a large project to study and develop. So, I'm wondering is there are any tool or feature in Visual Studio 2010 to get the complete class structure (NOT class view); In other words I need to get a good idea on how the solution is constructed and how classes and objects are used.

Is there any way?

Comment: how about generating an UML schema?

Comment: Where are you wandering to? (SCNR)

Comment: FYI: "**Wandering**: Walking or moving in a leisurely, casual, or aimless way". "**Wondering**: Desire or be curious to know something". I appreciate English may not be your first language, just saying, wandering is a completely different word to wondering.

Comment: @Freeman Sounds great. It will help lot. Can you please tell me how?

Comment: Google can offer you all the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

UML models help you understand  software systems
Please take a look at [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd409445.aspx)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Menu > View > Object Browser

This gives you a treeview of all the classes and objects you have created and are referenced in your project

Comment: This does not show the structure of the project, only separate classes.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on you project and click on the View Class diagram. this will show the classes structure to you. that will be easier to understand the structure of the project